# Rails 3.2 Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following Model classes:

```
class OptionCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :disabled, :list_index, :name
  has_many :options
end


class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :disabled, :name, :option_category_id
  belongs_to :option_category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :annual_fee, :bal_transfer_intro_apr_end, :bal_transfer_intro_apr_start, :balance_transfer_fee, :description, :image, :image_cache, :name, :pur_intro_apr_end, :pur_intro_apr_start, :sign_up_bonus, :sign_up_bonus_type, :url
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  has_and_belongs_to_many :options
end
```

In one of my controllers I receive an array of option ids, I would like to query for Products that have options that match those ids.  Is there an easy way to do this in Rails?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find all your Options and optimize away the N+1 by using `includes`:

```
Option.includes(:products).where(:id => array_of_ids)
```

This will perform a single `select * from options where id in [array_of_ids]` to load the options, extract the `product_id` fields, and perform a single additional `select * from products where id in [product_ids]` query.

You can make this easier on yourself by using `has_many :through`, and creating a model to wrap the joining table. If this model were called `ProductOptions`, you would be able to simply do this:

```
Product.find(ProductOptions.where(:option_id => array_of_option_ids).map(&:product_id).uniq)
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby.  Is there a more elegant way to do this? ` options = Option.includes(:products).where(:id => params[:options])
   product_ids = []
   options.each do |o| 
     product_ids += o.products.collect { |product| product.id }
   end
  
   @products = Product.where(:id => product_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.joins(:options).where(:options => {:id => params[:options]}).group(:id)
```